# Web Service in Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to recreate a web service in Azure.
 The web service needs to get data from an Azure database that needs to be exposed to SharePoint online.

The only options when I get when creating a web service in the azure Portal are as follows

- Web App
- Web App + SQL
- Function App

Do I need to create a Function app instead?.  Is a Function app equivalent to an On premise Web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of web service you want to *host* in Azure. E. g. if you have a dotnet / dotnet Core REST API,  you probably want to create an [**API App**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/api/) (just search for API App).

Comment: An "API App" is pretty much the same as a Web App -- just a different icon. Both should work. I have all my REST services created as "Web Apps" with no issues